# Getting an unexplained error from a simple SQL query in Oracle NoSQL Database cloud service

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

Here's a super basic question. I am trying to get the total row count for my table. I tried the following super simple query:

```
Select count(*) from myTable
```

in Oracle NoSQL Database cloud service console and also the OCI CLI.

But, I am getting the following error:

```
QUERY: Illegal Argument: Error: at (1, 7) Could not find function with name COUNT and arity 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the NoSQL console uses the simple REST interface to Oracle NoSQL, which does not support ordering results or aggregate queries.  If you're looking for a more capable UI that supports odrdered results and aggregates, you may want to give the IntelliJ plugin a try https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13052-oracle-nosql-database-connector.

If you're writing code then you'll find that the driver for the cloud service supports ordered results as well as aggregates.